# How to determine big-O for a function systematically?

Tags: java, big-o, time-complexity

Is their a methodical way to do this? Like if I were given this function:

```
public static int f2(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) 
{
   // N = initial value of (hi-lo+1) of 1st activation of f2
   if(lo == hi) 
        return lo;
   if(arr[hi] >= arr[lo])
       return f2(arr, lo+1, hi);
    return f2(arr, lo, hi-1);
}
```

Many of the resources I've looked at don't tell you step by step how to get the notation for a function you've never seen. Is there even a way to do this non-intuitively? If so, how would I get the worst case run time in terms of big-O? Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that there is no solid way  to calculate the time complexity of any function. Some, especially some recursive ones are exceptionally hard, and sometimes one can only derive a *tight* bond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's O(n) where `n` is `hi - lo + 1` and in each recursion the gap between `lo` and `hi` decreases by 1.

I suspect it's not possible to solve this generically as the worst case is the same as trying to solve the [Halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Indeed, +1 for the halting problem reference.